# SonicPoint Ni constantly dropping wifi connections

Tags: firewall, wifi

I am currently running into the problem of wireless connections on our SonicWall SonicPointNi WAPs dropping client connections.  I have researched the problem with changing as many settings as I possibly can and yet the device continues to drop clients.

To give you some background we have 4 SonicWall SonicPointNi wireless access points all connected to a SonicWall NSA 220 firewall that is also the wireless controller.  We are broadcasting two SSIDs, one for our office's primary users and a guest SSID.  I completed a wireless spectrum analysis and placed the WAPs on channels in the 2.4 GHz range on channels 1, 6, 11, and 6 respectively where the two devices on channel 6 are in complete opposite ends of the office building to prevent overlap of the two devices.

Now, what I saw during the times of the heaviest load (btw 35-50 clients connected)was that users would be constantly dropped from the network and have to repair their wireless connection in order to reconnect.

I first saw the recommendation to change the AP to broadcasting in G mode only with setting a beacon interval to 400ms and I have set the power settings on all of the devices to minimum to minimize any wireless overlap but yet clients are still dropping.

So here is my question to the group, are there any recommendations to further troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many headaches and work with SonicWall support, we upgraded the firmware on both the firewall and all of the WAPs.  So at this point, (1 week) the system has been stable.

**Note:  After some time we continued to have difficulty and problems with the SonicPoint WAPs so we completely replaced the WAPs with Ubiquiti Networks Access Points.  The cost was a lot less than what was spent on the sonicpoints and the controller software came with the devices.  We've had those devices in place for a few months now and we have not had a problem even with 40+ users on one WAP all streaming a WebEx conference.